# Parse HTTP response in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, http, angular7

Server returns data in this format: `{"query": 'queryName', 'result': []}`.

I need to get only result part, for that I did this:

```
export class RequestInterception implements HttpInterceptor {

  public constructor(private route: Router) {

  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
     if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return event.body['result'];
     }
    }, (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
             if (err.status === 401) {
               this.route.navigate(['/login']);
             }

          return throwError('backend comm error');

        }
    })

};
```

Inside `do` operator I tried this:

```
return event.body['result'];
```

But it still returns me whole object instead.

**AppModule** is:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterception,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Are you using an interceptor?

Comment: Sure, I use it: `intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {}`

Comment: Can you try logging `event.body['result']` to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform the response in the interceptor, then you can do it with a `map` operator. You can also use the `catchError` operator and then inside that, use `throwError` in case the status code is `401`.

Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, 
  HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse 
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private route: Router) { }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>, 
    next: HttpHandler
  ) {
    return next.handle(modified)
      .pipe(
        map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          event['body'] = event.body['result'];
          return event;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            this.route.navigate(['/login']);
          }
          return throwError('backend comm error');
        })
      );
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptor-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptor.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I get an error on: `event['body'] = { foo: 'bar' };`

Comment: Cause it is constant

Comment: My bad. I just pasted the same code from the stackblitz. It should be `event['body'] = event.body['result'];` I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An `HttpReponse` behaves like a JSON. For example, in order to get the body of your `response` you can do the following:

```
response_body = response["body"]
```

Of course, you have to subscribe.